Multiple Tabs / Tab strip in Safari Web App
I am trying to figure out how to create a (macOS\Safari) webapp from a given webpage (e.g. binance.com) that allows me to set & open multiple tabs of the same domain (ideally limited to that if possible at all & route any other domain to the default browser app).
I spent a considerable amount of time digging around, since I bascically don't even know what exact to search for. Therefore I learned a lot - unrelated - stuff. ;)
It appears it is a possible thing to do since e.g. https://www.bzgapps.com/unite offers a "wrapper" to do exactly that. I could "hack" my way into it (consider my limited knowledge) to find anything related e.g .plist settings or alike that does the trick but didnt got much further either.

Context
I am trading a lot and seek to create my "app" from specific exchanges who are too stupid to store my custom settings in my profile but in countless cookies & sideloaded content scripts.To ease up my life & even "bend" the UI more easily to my will while remaining "in control" about whats going on, I planned going this route.
While its easy to achieve in FireFox & Chrome their memory management is a nightmare for trading in the browser (real time data + charts + ... X tabs of active assets easily leads to several GB of consumed memory in Chrome)

How you can help?
No need to write me the thing. All I am asking is a olid pointer that could do the trick. (if thrid party, it must be open source since this environment is pretty sensitive & I am not in for experiments). But also some related docs already would be 100% than what I got as of now.
Appreciate any help/guidance/pointer.
